# “the right of doing" or " the right to do"?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

A sentence from an ACT English test:
The court agreed with Kevin that a person’s **right to wear** clothing of his or her own choosing is, in fact, protected by the Fourteenth Amendment.

Is it correct to say "...that a person's right of wearing..."? Or does it have to be an infinitive there?

Comment: The construction is normally "right + infinitive".

Comment: If you look up carefully chosen ["right of" + ing-form] examples, such as "right of walking" or "right of driving", in a Google search you will see that these strings _are_ in fact quite commonly used. But compare Google n-grams of say [right to wear clothing] and [right of wearing clothing] to compare idiomaticity. I'd avoid the ing-form variant.